# Behavior of lambda functions in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I have been studying leetcode problems and ran into one where I needed to increment the value of an existing key/value pair in a HashMap. I found the consensus was that the best way to do this in Java 8 is the following piece of code:

```
myMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

In this example, why does `v++` fail to work in place of `v + 1`?

Secondly, where might I go besides asking the question here to figure this out? I got the code to work but want to understand why my first instinct to put `v++` doesn't.

Comment: "fail to work"? What happened? A compile error? An exception?

Comment: It compiled just fine but did not actually increment the value of v, which led to the code giving an incorrect answer

Comment: Because `v++` returns `v` and then increments it by `1`. `v + 1` immediately returns `v + 1`. there is a chance that `++v` would work just like `v + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `v++` is the value of `v` *before* it was incremented.

Since the only thing that matters in this lambda is the return value, that would be equivalent of just using `(k, v) -> v`.

If you wanted to use a shorthand `++v` would work, but `v + 1` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`v++` returns the previous value of `v`.

For example:

```
int v = 5;
int newValue = v++;
// newValue is now equal to 5
```

If your lambda function returns the old value of `v`, that's probably not what you intended.

If you had used `++v` instead of `v++` it might have done what you want, since `++v` increments `v` and returns the *new* value.

But still, `v+1` is clearer. Your lambda function is supposed to *return one higher than v*, not to increment `v`.

Comment: To follow on this, why is only v + 1 necessary rather than v = v + 1?

Comment: @Efie: `v` is a local variable in your lambda (well, technically a parameter, but that behaves an awful lot like a local variable) . Modifying it does nothing, really. The only relevant part of that lambda is the value that it returns (which is implicitly the return value of the expression).